# Cannot register appium node to appium hub

Tags: selenium-webdriver, grid, appium, hub

im trying to use appium hub like this (cuz i need device-farm plugin)
`appium server --use-plugins=device-farm --plugin-device-farm-platform=android --config hubConfig.json`
hubConfig file:

```
{
  "server": {
    "port": 4444,
    "address": "10.18.21.52"
  }
}
```

or like this `appium -a 10.18.21.52 -p 4444 --use-plugins=device-farm --plugin-device-farm-platform=android`
How i understand, this the same things

But when i try register node with command:
`appium server --nodeconfig nodeConfig.json -p 2222`
nodeConfig file:

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "platformName": "android",
      "deviceName": "any"
    },
    {
      "platformName": "ios",
      "deviceName": "any"
    }
  ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":30000,
    "url":"http://10.18.21.79:2222/",
    "host": "10.18.21.79",
    "port": 2222,
    "maxSession": 5,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "10.18.21.52"
  }
}
```

I get 404 error and smth like "cannot register grid"
And on hub i have errors like this:

```
[HTTP] --> GET /grid/register/
[HTTP] {}
[HTTP] No route found for /grid/register/
```

Whats wrong?) Thanks for ur time and answers

I need connect appium node to appium hub